# Custom QProcess object to wait for output before returning

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qprocess

*note: the title does not convey the question exactly, feel free to edit as is necessary*

1. Info on classes and descriptions
2. Problem
3. Code examples, etc
4. TL;DR

**1. Info:**

I have created a custom QProcess class called `m_Proc`.

```
#include "misc_serv"

using namespace misc_serv;

class GEN_SERVSHARED_EXPORT m_Proc : public QProcess
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int exitCode = -1;
    QString _out;
    s_i_combo si;
    QList<s_i_combo> sch_in_List;

    m_Proc(QList<s_i_combo> i_s_list, QObject *parent = 0);
    m_Proc(s_i_combo i_s_obj, QObject *parent);
    m_Proc(QObject *parent);

    void setProcessBlocks(s_i_combo _si);
    void setProcessBlocks(QList<s_i_combo> _si_list);
    ~m_Proc() {}

private:
    s_i_combo getSearchInput();
    void initConnectors();

public slots:
    void myReadyReadStandardOutput();
    void myFinished(int i);

signals:
    void finishedSignal();
};
```

The **purpose** of this class is to use the signals emitted from the QProcess parent, which will allow me to `read*()` from and `write()` to the `QProcess`.

When the final output is reached, the `QProcess::finished(int)`, is connected to a method to assign the final output and exit code of the `QProcess`

a signal is then emitted from `m_Proc` which will notify the parent class The signal named (quite creatively) `finishedSignal`

`m_Proc` is handled by another parent class named `gen_serv`.

```
#include "m_proc.h"

class GEN_SERVSHARED_EXPORT gen_serv : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QObject *parent;
    QProcess *p;
    int MSEC = 1000;
    m_Proc *m;

    int exitCode = -1;
    QString _proc_out;

    void init_connector();

private slots:
    void getResults();

public:
    gen_serv(QObject *_parent = new QObject());
    virtual ~gen_serv();
    void runCommand(const QString _prog);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, const QStringList args);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, const QString _sSearch, const QString _sInput);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, const QStringList args, const QString _sSearch, const QString _sInput);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, s_i_combo siCombo);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, const QStringList args, s_i_combo siCombo);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, QList<s_i_combo> siList);
    void runCommand(const QString _prog, const QStringList args, QList<s_i_combo> siList);

    QString getRunCommand_Output();
    int getRunCommand_ExitCode();

    QProcess* createProcess(QString cmd/*, int t_sec = 30*/);

};
```

gen_serv has various "constructor methods" for `m_Proc`. These constructor methods calls `runCommand`. These constructors with their parameters allow various processing capabilities ranging from a basic program execution to a detailed I/O process.

**2. The Problem:**

In my qt console application, I create a `gen_serv` object, and use this to "runCommands", e.g. :

```
//main.cpp

gen_serv *gen_proc
gen_proc = new gen_serv();
gen_proc->runCommand("sh", QStringList()
                         << "-c"
                         << "echo sleeping; sleep 2; echo hello...");
qDebug() << gen_proc->_proc_out;
```

based on how my m_Proc works, it will *should* return: "hello..."

the command to be run above is the same as (to my understanding):

```
$ sh -c "echo sleeping; sleep 2; echo hello..."
sleeping
hello...
```

**BUT:** it returns an empty QString, and:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(gen_proc->exitCode);
```

**outputs** : "-1"

**3. Extra code examples, etc** - This led me to believe:

the issue does not lie in `m_Proc`, but in my parent class `gen_serv`.

Currently, after calling `void gen_serv::runCommand()`, I run the `QObject::connect()` as shown below (`getResults()` just gets the `_proc_out` and `exitCode` and assigns them to `gen_serv` for accessor methods):

```
QObject::connect(m, SIGNAL(finishedSignal()), this, SLOT(getResults()));
```

However this is executed, and `runCommand()` returns to `main.cpp` where `qDebug()` immediately calls the `gen_proc->_proc_out` and qDebug() will output:

```
_gen_proc->_proc_out = ""
_gen_proc->exitcode = -1
```

**4. TL;DR**

What I need:

I need to devise a method which will run after/or replacing the connect (in `gen_serv`).

This method will wait until the signal is emitted, so the `runCommand()` , which calls the `QProcess.start()`, will not return until the `finishedSignal` from `m_Proc` is emitted, thus guaranteeing a valid output/exit code value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, I cannot tell if it is a good one or not, but it works.

**Possible Solution:** (using `QProcess::wait*()`'s)

In the method (`gen_serv::init_connector()`) where I call the `QObject::connect()`, I changed/added a few extra lines.

```
void gen_serv::init_connector(){
    if (m->waitForStarted()) {
        QObject::connect(m, SIGNAL(finishedSignal()), this, SLOT(getResults()));
        if (!m->waitForFinished())
            qDebug() << "program is hanging, check m_Proc description for possible hang issues...: \n" << m->errorString();
    }
    else{
        if (m->errorString().contains("No such file or directory"))
            qDebug() << "check program and arguments - something seems wrong. Cannot find something... : \n" << m->errorString();
        else
            qDebug() << m->errorString();
    }
}
```

The solution is pretty straight forward, but nonetheless, I will provide a short description:

- Firstly, one checks if the process has actually started. If not, then display an appropriate message with the error string.

*note*: I noticed that an error string like:

> "exec*p*: No such file or directory usually implies that either the `program` is not found

i.e. incorrect path or there are surplus arguments or the application does not take any arguments

- If the QProcess is started, then `connect()` the `signal` and `slot`. Followed by the `waitForFinished()`.

Reason for the `waitForFinished()` is this method waits for the QProcess::finished(int) signal.

This allows the application to wait until the process has completed (which is what I require).

Hope this helps someone